# How to use "class" the word as parameter function calls in python

Tags: python, elementtree

I am writing an XML generator per my manager's request. For less typings' sake, I decided using ElementTree as parser and SimpleXMLWriter as writer.

The result XML require attributes named "class". e.g.

```
<Node class="oops"></Node>
```

As the official tutorial suggested, to write an XML node just use this method:

```
w.element("meta", name="generator", value="my application 1.0")
```

So I wrote:

```
w.element("Node", class="oops")
```

python fails yawning SyntaxError. Any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess SimpleXMLWriter developers meant this solution:

```
w.element("Node", None, {'class': 'oops'})
```

or

```
w.element("Node", attrib={'class': 'oops'})
```

Answer (score 5):

What steveha has written is true. As in any language, keywords can't be used for different purposes.

What you can do, if you must use "class" is this:

```
w.element("Node", **{'class': 'oops'})
```

Answer (score 3):

`class` is a reserved word in Python.  You just can't use it for a variable name, any more than you can have a variable called `class` in C++.

The usual abbreviation for `class` is either `klass` or `cls`.

Here is an official list of reserved words in Python:

http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords